# Mouse stops moving after a every few seconds, but revives after click action

Tags: linux, mouse, arch-linux, kernel

I am using Arch Linux and according to "uname -r" my Linux Kernel Version is 3.10.10-1-ARCH.
This problem appeared after a full system update recently.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it wireless? Did you replace the batteries?

Comment: No, it is a cabled USB Mouse. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse and experienced the same problem? Try to eliminate hardware and reinstall drivers.

Answer (score 0):

install nano:

```
$ sudo pacman -S nano
```

edit the file:

```
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf
```

to do:

```
sudo nano /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf
```

[sudo] password for USER: (write the password of your PC)

to replace :

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND="auto"
```

by:

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0
```

It works for me.